# Is it possible for format a Excel Table adding data with Markers with SyncFusion XlsIO ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, syncfusion

I have an excel file (that I use as a template) with two rows. The first one for the table headers, and the second one with the data markers (eg. %Customer.Name). The two rows are setted as a table in excel.

When I do ApplyMarkers, for example two data rows are created, but just the first one is part of the table (with correct table formatting). The excel table isn't "refreshed" to include all the data rows added.

This is something that I was able to do with ExtremeML doing simply :
table.Fill(reportData, DataSetName);

Is is possible, without post processing after applying the markers?

Thanks in advance,
Ricardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not supported.

To accomplish the same result we have to fill the data first and then for the range we want to make a table do:

```
sheet.ListObjects.Create("Table1", dataRange);
```